# How to specify a specific range for a loop?

Tags: functions, function-construction

I'm having trouble with setting up a particular range in a loop for my programming. Now I have a defined range of data (not continuous numbers) that needs to be applied in a loop. Since the aim for my code is to generate functions/expressions with the range automatically, I need to figure out a way to applied those data.

The code is

```
MapThread[(Subscript[C, #1][x, y] := 
     Subscript[q, 2 #1 - 1] + 
      x*Subscript[q, 2 #1] - (Subscript[q, #2] + 
        y*Subscript[q, #2 + 1])) &, {Range[], Range[]}];
```

data for #1 is: 3, 4, 5, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6.
data for #2 is: 1, 2, 4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 5.

As u can see from the code, I cannot simply define the range in the loop. 
My idea is to create a list for the data and maybe apply it in the loop? thx for ur help!

Comment: 1) Please provide an equivalent code without `Subscript` (unless your question actually pertains to `Subscript`)... it only occludes your intent 2) Why haven't you inserted your "data" for #1 and #2 instead of `Range[]` (which does nothing, since it needs at least 1 arg) 3) Please edit your posts to make it proper English. We like to avoid "u", "thx", "ur", etc. and keep it clean.

Comment: If the OP could describe as precisely as possible what it is that he/she wants to do, rather than provide a vague explanation and non-functional code, then maybe it will be possible to help.

Comment: Also, you should note that since the list for `#1` contains repeated elements you're just redefining `Subscript[c, #1][x, y]` n times, which I guess isn't what you're after

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are trying to define a collection of functions that are indexed by two variables #1 and #2. This code replaces #1 with `i`, #2 with `j` and defines all the functions within a `Table`.

```
Table[c[i_, j_, x_, y_] := q[2 j - 1] + x*q[2 i] - (q[j] + y*q[j + 1]), 
     {j, {1, 2, 4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 5}}, {i, {3, 4, 5, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6}}];
```

So now, for example, there are a collection of functions `c` indexed by the `i` and `j`, each defined in terms of `x`, `y`, and `q[ ]`. For example:

```
c[3, 4, x, y]
-q[4] - y q[5] + x q[6] + q[7]
```

Comment: +1 for a great effort in trying to understand the question. But I haven't the slightest idea on how close you could be from the "real" question :)

Comment: @belisarius I guess I was hoping to prompt "but that's not what I meant" from the OP so we could figure it out... it seemed like an interesting mix of naivete (such as malformed Range[ ] comamnds) and sophistication (such as MapThread).